# JSONObject["locationInfo"] not a string

Tags: java, json, gson

Sorry for the repeated question.I have been banging my head on this since hours.
I am trying to parse json to an object of setter/getter class.

```
String location = request.getParameter("location");
System.out.print(location);

org.json.JSONObject json = new org.json.JSONObject(location);
/* JSONObject js = json.getJSONObject("locationInfo");
String mapLoc = js.getString("locationInfo"); */
String mapLoc = json.getString("locationInfo");  <--- receiving the error on this line

Gson gsn = new Gson();
MapObject mLocObj = gsn.fromJson(mapLoc, MapObject.class);
System.out.println(mLocObj.getLongitude());
double longitude = Double.parseDouble(mLocObj.getLongitude());
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(mLocObj.getLatitude());
```

Here is my json string location:

```
{"locationInfo":{"latitude":"19.3828815","longitude":"72.8296205"}}
```

This is the error log:

```
19: System.out.print(location);
20: 
21: org.json.JSONObject json = new org.json.JSONObject(location);
22: String mapLoc = json.getString("locationInfo");
23: 
24:     Gson gsn = new Gson();
25:     MapObject mLocObj = gsn.fromJson(mapLoc, MapObject.class);


Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["locationInfo"] not a string.
at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:639)
at org.apache.jsp.mapView_jsp._jspService(mapView_jsp.java:88)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at       org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: In your json locationInfo is an object (note: { }); is a string when "localInfo": "something"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In json location is another json object.

so you would use:

```
json.getJSONObject("locationInfo")
```

furthermore for latitude then:

```
json.getJSONObject("locationInfo").getString("latitude")
```

Comment: It gives me this error.. org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["locationInfo"] not found.

Comment: This is kinda strange.
As you state in your description:

    org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["locationInfo"] not a string.

this attribute should be present and I tried it in a program and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

You need to check whether your "locationInfo" string is null:

```
if (json.isNull("locationInfo")){
  mapLoc = "";
} else {
  mapLoc = json.getString("locationInfo");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that in fact "locationInfo" is not a string but a JSONObject.

Take a look at [documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject%28java.lang.String%29)

You could try to get

```
org.json.JSONObject jsonlocationInfo = json.getJSONObject("locationInfo");
```

Comment: and how will i convert this to string? so that i can use it in gsn.fromjson(..) method

Comment: once you have saved content of object locationInfo into jsonlocationInfo  variable, you can access all properties, that are base types, in example you could take latitude value as:
String latitude=    jsonlocationInfo .getString("latitude");

Comment: It gives me this error.. org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["locationInfo"] not found.

Comment: You could try with getNames method to print all json properties to see if the objeject is parsed correctly or not and how object representation of JSON is composed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two different libraries json.org and goolge gson. By using gson you can get locationIfno string as below

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(location);
String locationInfo =  jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("locationInfo").toString();

{"latitude":"19.3828815","longitude":"72.8296205"}
```

finally parse it

```
 Gson gsn = new Gson();
 MapObject mLocObj = gsn.fromJson(locationInfo , MapObject.class);
```